# spring transaction and aop

Tags: spring, transactions, aop

I'm writing a simple application with spring, I defined my daos and services with spring annotations and defined hibernate as the orm and transaction manager like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:env/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.skyfence.management.cm.model</value>
    </list>
</property>




    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

like you can see I'm using annotations for the transactions management,
Until this point everything works fine.
Then I added a Logger Aspect to add log4j printouts before and after every method so I added the following to my applicationContext.xml

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

and created a new annotated aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect
{
}
```

The problem is that from that point hibernate is no longer working and I'm getting the following exception:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

I suspect that somehow by adding the aspect the transactions stopped working but I have no idea how to solve it

Any help will be appreciated,